# Is there an alternative to GETCWD() in Fortran 2003-2008

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003, fortran2008

The GNU Extension to the GNU Fortran compiler provides the subroutine `GETCWD()` that well, gets the current working directory. However, my code has to be portable to the `ifort` and `nagfor` compiler as well and I use F2003 features.

So, is there an alternative to `GETCWD()` for F2003 and later?

I have the standard here but it's quite sizeable and I've been going through it for a while now and haven't found anything useful...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the `ISO_C_Binding` and call the corresponding `C` functions:

cwd.c:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
/* Windows */
#include <direct.h>
#define GETCWD _getcwd

#else
/* Unix */
#include <unistd.h>
#define GETCWD getcwd

#endif

void getCurrentWorkDir( char *str, int *stat )
{
  if ( GETCWD(str, sizeof(str)) == str ) {
    *stat = 0;
  } else {
    *stat = 1;
  }
}
```

test.F90:

```
program test
 use ISO_C_Binding, only: C_CHAR, C_INT
 interface
   subroutine getCurrentWorkDir(str, stat) bind(C, name="getCurrentWorkDir")
     use ISO_C_Binding, only: C_CHAR, C_INT
     character(kind=C_CHAR),intent(out) :: str(*)
     integer(C_INT),intent(out)         :: stat
    end subroutine
  end interface
  character(len=30)   :: str
  integer(C_INT)      :: stat

  str=''
  call getCurrentWorkDir(str, stat)
  print *, stat, trim(str)

end program
```

This code is valid for Windows and Unix-derivates (Linux, OSX, BSD, etc. )

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! :) I am inexperienced with interfacing with C but will try. Am I correct if I say this will cause my makefile to become slightly more complicated, as I need to define a compiler for the C?

Comment: It depends... To compile this example I simply used `gfortran -Wall -Wextra -g  cwd.c test.F90`.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in the comments, you can make use of `get_environment_variable` which is standard Fortran (e.g. F2008 13.7.67).  This example program queries the value of `$PWD`, which should contain the directory your shell is in when you invoked the executable.

```
program test
 implicit none
 character(len=128) :: pwd
 call get_environment_variable('PWD',pwd)
 print *, "The current working directory is: ",trim(pwd)
end program
```

And its output:

```
casey@convect code % pwd
/home/casey/code
casey@convect code % so/getpwd 
 The current working directory is: /home/casey/code
```

This is standard Fortran, but its portability will be limited to Unix and Unix-like shells that set this variable.

Another option while standard but ugly (in my opinion) would be to use `execute_command_line` to run a command that can output the working directory to a temporary file (e.g. `pwd > /tmp/mypwd`), then reading that file.

Comment: `PWD` is not available for windows, you would need to query `CD`.

Comment: Thank you Casey! :) Because portability is definitely an issue in this case, I accepted Alexander's answer but yours is definitely going to be of use to me and others in the future.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I tried changing `PWD` to `CD`: `call get_environment_variable('CD',currDir)`.

But this does not work in windows (I have tried using both gfortran and ifort). Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer contains two errors (it passes the wrong value as the length of the string to `GETCWD`, and leaves in the `C_NULL_CHAR`). This answer corrects those mistakes and makes the interface more usable from Fortran.

The basic idea is the same: call `getcwd` or `_getcwd` using C, and call the C wrapper using Fortran's C interoperability features. On the Fortran side, a wrapper subroutine is used to handle the string length, so it does not have to be passed explicitly.

Also, `C_INT` and `C_CHAR` are not necessary the same as default integers and default characters, which are wanted on the Fortran side (though in practice I am not aware of any system where `C_CHAR` and default char differ). The wrapper also converts those. Also, the string returned from C contains the terminating `C_NULL_CHAR`, which must be removed for the string to be usable on the Fortran side.

The C code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <direct.h>
#define GETCWD _getcwd
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define GETCWD getcwd
#endif

/* Return 0 on success, 1 on error. */
int getCWDHelper(char *str, int len)
{
    return GETCWD(str, len) != str;
}
```

The Fortran code:

```
module cwd
    use iso_c_binding, only: C_INT, C_CHAR, C_NULL_CHAR
    implicit none
    private
    public :: getCWD

    interface
        function getCWDHelper(str, len) bind(C, name="getCWDHelper")
            use iso_c_binding, only: C_INT, C_CHAR
            integer(kind=C_INT) :: getCWDHelper
            character(kind=C_CHAR), intent(out) :: str(*)
            integer(kind=C_INT), value :: len
        end function getCWDHelper
    end interface

contains

    ! Writes the current working directory path into str.
    ! Returns 0 on success, or 1 on error.
    function getCWD(str)
        integer :: getCWD
        character(*), intent(out) :: str

        integer :: i, length
        character(len=len(str), kind=C_CHAR) :: str_copy

        ! Call the C helper, passing the length as the correct int kind
        getCWD = getCWDHelper(str_copy, len(str_copy, kind=C_INT))

        if (getCWD /= 0) then
            str = '' ! Error, clear the string
            return
        end if

        ! Copy the C_CHAR string to the output string,
        ! removing the C_NULL_CHAR and clearing the rest.
        length = index(str_copy, C_NULL_CHAR) - 1
        do i = 1, length
            str(i:i) = char(ichar(str_copy(i:i)))
        end do
        str(length+1:) = ''
    end function getCWD

end module
```

Test code:

```
program test
    use cwd, only: getCWD
    implicit none

    character(len=255) :: path
    integer :: error

    error = getCWD(path)

    print *, error
    if (error == 0) print *, path
end program
```

Making the return value allocatable and looping to get a sufficient size is left as an exercise to the reader.