# current working directory when executing a dll

Tags: c, dll, fortran

I run some fortran source code from a C program using a **dll**. I want to use **CALL GETCWD(DIRNAME)** in Fortran to access files. Is the Current Working Directory (CWD) the directory where my fortran dll is located or where my C-code is located?

Comment: ***C**urrent **W**orking **D**irectory*. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html. It's the directory where you started the program from.

Comment: Be aware that `getcwd` is not part of the fortran standard but a common extension of various compilers such as gfortran, ifort, etc ... .  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279228/is-there-an-alternative-to-getcwd-in-fortran-2003-2008

Comment: @kvantour i didn't know that, thanks! i'm using gfortran.

Comment: @CristiFati the source you link says "the current working directory of the calling process". I assume the calling process is then the DLL and not my C-code right?

Comment: No, it's the executable that results from building your *C* code (and probably that loads the *.dll*).

Comment: ok that makes sense! Thanks! Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CWD* stands for ***C**urrent **W**orking **D**irectory*, and it's (usually) the directory where the current process was launched from. Check [[Man7]: GETCWD(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) for more details. I prepared a small example for better understanding what's going on.

*code00.c*:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PATH_SIZE 0x0200


int main()
{
    char buf[PATH_SIZE];
    if (getcwd(buf, PATH_SIZE) == NULL) {
        printf("Error %d getting CWD\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("CWD: [%s]\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.c
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o cwd code00.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.c  cwd
> [064bit prompt]> ./cwd
> CWD: [/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561]
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> pushd .. && ./q054306561/cwd && popd
> /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561
> CWD: [/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow]
> /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> mkdir test && pushd test && ../cwd && popd
> /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561/test /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561
> CWD: [/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561/test]
> /mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q054306561
> ```